# CSS: Can't get text to float to the right of my image

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

Should be so simple and I've been reading enough posts here that this should be a snap. So of course, it's not....

I'm simply trying to float text to the right of my image. Been trying different tacks with my position, display and floats. All to no avail.

If you look at https://staging.hellodadventures.com and scroll down to where the "DadVentures Deal" appears, about midway through the page, you'll see it.

Here's my code first the HTML:

```css
.dadventures-deal img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  z-index: 251;
}

.dadventures-deal h3 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #F00;
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 12px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  z-index: 250;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-deals">
  <a href="https://staging.hellodadventures.com/event/santa-monica-pier-aquarium/" title="Santa Monica Pier Aquarium">
    <div class="feature">
      <figure class="fixedratio" style="background: url('https://staging.hellodadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/healthebay-aquarium-e1551648109222.jpg');"></figure>
      <div class="feature-bottom">
        <h2>Santa Monica Pier Aquarium </h2>
        <div class="dadventures-deal"><img src="https://staging.hellodadventures.com/wp-content/themes/dadvation/img/symbol-dadventures.png" alt="DadVentures Deals">
          <h3>DadVentures Deal</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Again, should be straightforward, but that pesky CSS.....

Comment: use display:flex instead of float

Comment: I updated my answer if you dont want to use flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add display:inline-block and clear:none or clear:right to h3
add display:block to img

Comment: h3 doesn't need floating only float:left to the image is enough but it works either way :)

Comment: Thanks! Really worked great. Didn't think of the clear: none idea but it sure worked!

Answer (score 0):

add `clear: none;` to your h3 tag